# rails model method is just saying nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It's almost my first method in **model** so I think I'm missing some very fundamental part in here. But I couldn't find out what's the problem for 2 hours. Your help will save me!

```
# just simple UserKey(to find user rapidly) model
class UserKey < ActiveRecord::Base

def filter_name(name)
  self.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
end
```

Then I do `@user_key.filter_name("jeongbin")` in my rails console and it's just saying nil even though I saved jeongbin in my user_keys table. When I just do it with `@user_key.where("name LIKE ?", "%jeongbin%")` in my console, it's working!

I think my poor knowledge is missing some basic parts. Any advice will help me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method as:-

```
def self.filter_name(name)
  self.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
end
```

In rails console, search the user as:-

```
UserKey.filter_name("jeongbin")
```

`def filter_name(name)` will be called on a object of `UserKey model`, so it is showing result when it is called with `@user_key` as `"jeongbin"` is there in that object otherwise it is nil.

But to search on all the record in `user_keys table`, it should be call with the `UserKey Model` and the method should be a class method as `def self.filter_name(name)`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that self thing is related with UserKey(not to my @user_key variable kind of things). Also with your comment i fount that I made method with the same name(big mistake). But I could have a chance to think of self and model thing again and learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a misplaced `self`.

```
class UserKey < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.filter_name(name)
    where 'name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%"
  end

end
```

I usually prefer this notation, to accomplish the same thing, as it organizes everything into one spot, and reduces the number of `self.`s, as your codebase grows.

```
class UserKey < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def filter_name(name)
      where 'name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%"
    end

  end    
end
```

You will need to call it like

`UserKey.filter_name 'some_name'`

If you want to keep it an instance method, use this:

```
class UserKey < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def filter_name(name)
      where 'name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%"
    end

  end   


  def filter_name(name) 
    self.class.filter_name(name) 
  end

end
```

Comment: You made a huge advice to me!(I saw your answer after i accepted @Shamsul Haque 's answer) I didn't know exactly about this, just some little knowledge from other sites.. But it's very clear with your comment and Big Lesson to me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, also I didn't know that where clause could be used without anything before. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, you very rarely need `self.`. The 2 most common cases are probably to get the class, as in my example, and to assign an attribute (like `self.some_attribute = 'some_value'`. Otherwise, you can probably just try to skip it, for starters.

Comment: I have other filters so I thought I need `self.` to concatenate those filters. I think I'll understand what you commented after some more learning. Thank you!